# Given a list of n points, how can I generate a matrix that contains the distance from every point to every other point using numpy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I am trying to rewrite the following matlab code in python:

```
repmat(points, 1, length(points)) - repmat(points', length(points),1);
```

`points` is an array that contain the radian value of several points.

The above code gives me a matrix output like this:

```
 0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
-1   0   1  -1   0   1  -1   0   1
-2  -1   0  -2  -1   0  -2  -1   0
 0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
-1   0   1  -1   0   1  -1   0   1
-2  -1   0  -2  -1   0  -2  -1   0
 0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
-1   0   1  -1   0   1  -1   0   1
-2  -1   0  -2  -1   0  -2  -1   0
```

Which i can easily manipulate to get the distance from each point to every other point.

I was just wondering if there's a *one liner* way to do it using numpy?

I tried the following which didn't work:

```
np.tile(points, (1, len(points))) - 
            np.tile(points.T, (len(points), 1))
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: FYI, in MATLAB you would actually prefer to use `bsxfun` than `repmat` for this: `bsxfun(@minus,points,points')`. `bsxfun` is the MATLAB analogue of Python's automatic broadcasting mentioned by Suever.

Comment: @Dan No public links, sadly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MATLAB, you had to use `repmat` because you needed the arrays on the left and right side of the `-` to be the same size. With numpy, this does not have to be the case thanks to numpy's [automatic broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#broadcasting-rules). Instead, you can simply subtract one from the other and the automatic broadcasting will create your result of the expected size.

```
# Create some example data
points = np.array([[1,2,3,4]]);

# Just subtract the transpose from points
B = points - points.T

#   array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#          [-1,  0,  1,  2],
#          [-2, -1,  0,  1],
#          [-3, -2, -1,  0]])
```

If `points` is instead just a 1D array, then @JoshAdel's answer should work for you (which also uses broadcasting) or you could convert it to a 2D array.

Comment: Thanks! That was really neat and straight forward! @Suever

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to take a look at [`scipy.spatial.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist)

But for constructing the original matrix you're looking for, if `points` is just a 1D array:

```
points = np.array([1,2,3,4])
points[:,None] - points[None,:]
```

If you have a 2D array, then @Suever's transpose method works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the matlab code.  However, just trying to calculate euclidean distance from every column vector to every other column vector:

```
np.sqrt((np.square(A[:, None].T - A.T)).sum(axis=2))

array([[ 0.,  3.,  6.,  0.,  3.,  6.,  0.,  3.,  6.],
       [ 3.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  0.,  6.,  3.,  0.,  6.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  6.,  0.,  3.,  6.,  0.,  3.,  6.],
       [ 3.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  0.,  6.,  3.,  0.,  6.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  6.,  0.,  3.,  6.,  0.,  3.,  6.],
       [ 3.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  0.,  6.,  3.,  0.,  6.,  3.,  0.]])
```